# Derivative inside a trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

Let $B : \mathbb R^{m \times n} \to \mathbb R^{p \times p}$. Let $k_{ij}$ denote the $(i,j)$-th entry of matrix $K$. Is the following equation correct?

$$\text{Tr} \left(\frac{\partial B(K)}{\partial k_{ij}}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial \text{Tr}(B(K))}{\partial K}\right)_{ij}$$

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What is $B(K)$ ?

Comment: $B(K)$ is a function

Comment: What properties does that function have? What about its domain and codomain? I think you need to add more context.

Comment: Yes, the trace is continuous, so you can move limits across it, and it is linear, so you can move derivatives across it. @evaristegd Doesn't matter what $B$ is, really.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks! @runway44

Summary
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\text{Tr} \left(\dfrac{\partial B(K)}{\partial k_{ij}}\right)&=&\text{Tr}\left(\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta k_{ij}\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{B(k_{ij}+\Delta k_{ij})-B(k_{ij})}{\Delta k_{ij}}\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta k_{ij}\rightarrow 0} \text{Tr}\left(\dfrac{B(k_{ij}+\Delta k_{ij})-B(k_{ij})}{\Delta k_{ij}}\right)\quad \text{(Trace is continuous)}\\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta k_{ij}\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\text{Tr} (B(k_{ij}+\Delta k_{ij}))-\text{Tr}(B(k_{ij}))}{\Delta k_{ij}} \quad\text{(Trace is linear)}\\
&=&\dfrac{\partial \text{Tr}(B(K))}{\partial k_{ij}}\\
&=&\left(\dfrac{\partial \text{Tr}(B(K))}{\partial K}\right)_{ij}
\end{array}
$$